# Error in get: object input$tableid_cell_clicked not found

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to observe the cell_clicked event on one of my datatables.
Normally I'd do it like this:

```
shiny::observeEvent(input$tableId_cell_clicked),{
  ...
}
```

The table I'm using now has a tableId that's stored in a variable. I'm trying the following:

```
shiny::observeEvent(get(paste0("input$", self$name, "_cell_clicked")), {
  ...
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Error in get: object 'input$Macrolaag_cell_clicked' not found
```

The creation happens like this:

```
#server side
output[[self$name]] <- DT::renderDataTable( ... )

#ui side
shiny::column(12, DT::dataTableOutput(self$name))
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use `input[[your_id_var]]`

Comment: I guess you mean `shiny::observeEvent(get(paste0(input[[self$name]], "_cell_clicked"))` ? If so, this still gets me an error. This time it is `Error in get: object '_cell_clicked' not found`

Comment: No I mean: `shiny::observeEvent({input[[paste0(self$name, "_cell_clicked")]]})`

Comment: This does the trick. Thank you. I don't understand why though.

Comment: The server function's `input` variable is accessed like a `list()`. We can use `$` or `[[..]]` to pass the `id` of the input we'd like to get. Above you are using the same pattern to pass the `datatable` to an `output`. Please see my below example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fully working example:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("iris_out")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$iris_out<- renderDT({iris})
  
  table_name <- "iris_out"
  
  shiny::observeEvent({input[[paste0(table_name, "_cell_clicked")]]}, {
    clicked_input_id <- paste0(table_name, "_cell_clicked")
    # input[[clicked_input_id]] is the same as input$iris_out_cell_clicked
    cat("input_id:", clicked_input_id, "\n")
    print(input[[clicked_input_id]])
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```